# How can I convert a Discord bot command to a Discord slash command in Python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a Python Discord bot that uses the discord.ext.commands module to implement a /last_message command that accepts a discord.Member object as an argument.

I want to convert this command to a slash command, so that users can type /last_message @username and pass @username as an argument. I've tried adding the @bot.slash_command() decorator instead of @bot.command(), but the command doesn't seem to work when I try to use it because I'am using Replit and it seems Replit doesn't support slash commands.

Can someone provide an example of how to properly convert a Discord bot command to a Discord slash command in Pythonfor this last_message command?

I tried this code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import pytz
from webserver import keep_alive

intents = discord.Intents.all()


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)

@bot.command(name='last_message')
async def last_message(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    newest_message = None
    newest_channel = None
    for channel in bot.get_all_channels():
        if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):
            async for message in channel.history(limit=300):
                if message.author == user:
                    if newest_message is None or message.created_at > newest_message.created_at:
                        newest_message = message
                        newest_channel = channel

    if newest_message is not None:
        now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
        message_age = now - newest_message.created_at
        days_old = message_age.days
        response_time = newest_message.created_at + timedelta(hours=1)
        response = f"Newest message by {user.mention} is:\n\n{newest_message.content}\n\nSent by {user.display_name} in {newest_channel.mention} on {response_time.strftime('%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p')}\n\nIt was sent {days_old} days ago."
    else:
        response = f"No messages found for {user.display_name} ({user.name})."

    await ctx.send(response)
keep_alive()
bot.run('MY TOKEN')
```

Comment: You might want to switch to a different Discord library. Try Disnake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@bot.tree.command()
```

Reference: [Command Tree](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=tree%20command#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.command)
Hope this helped :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34494701)